# Automated COMMIT in Subversion

Tags: svn

I have a J2EE application what is deploy into more application servers (Glassfish, JBoss, Oracle Application Server). I intend to split the existing project structure where each server would have its own branch and the development would use only the trunk.

All the JAVA files would be replicated to all braches and all server specific files (configuration XML, build XML, etc) would be spread from the trunk into the branches, based on properties.

I am searching for a solution what after commiting in TRUNK does automaticaly this. Is it possible? Or should I create an external application for this?

Thank you,
SK

Comment: That sounds a lot like Git submodule.

Comment: Hi Bartek,the only problem is that we are not allowed to use GIT